# Laravel 5.6 Routing doesn't work

Tags: laravel

First, I am not new to Laravel. I don't understand why this problem happens.  I'm working with Laravel on Homestead. When I first load app, welcome screen appears. Then I change routing, "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" appears. I remove all the routing web.php file, delete welcome blade file, again reload root url welcome page appears. Though I don't have any route in web.php and welcome.blade.php file. I clear cache, try some different things, but same thing happens again.

Comment: Because you dont have any routes!

Comment: i add route  in web.php file and return 'Hello' from route.e.g Route::get('/', function() { return 'Hello';} This returns welcome page again.

Comment: Read laravel documentation please

Comment: I worked with Laravel before and I know how routing works. I really don't know this problem is related to Laravel or Homestead.

Comment: Please, add code of yours `web.php`.

Comment: Having the exact same issue! :(

Comment: guys... if is laravel 5.6 (newer version), then something changed, show us the code! the controller and route file (web.php)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with homestead and not with laravel , the welcome page you seen is not the laravel welcome page.
Try to make the correct path for your project directory . and follow [the laravel homestead doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead)